# Convert JSON object to list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a JSON object

```
{{“a”:1, ”b”:2}, {“c”:3, ”d”:4}, {“e”:5, ”f”:6}}
```

This has to be changed to

```
{{{a, 1}, {b, 2}}, {{c, 3}, {d, 4}}, {{e, 5}, {f, 6}}}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: How did you get the 1st list that you show into Mathematica? It does not look like a valid list. Please show what it looks like in `FullForm`. Once we understand what you have actually imported, I think the list manipulation part will be easy.

Comment: How general/deep it should be/work?

Answer (score 4):

The original "list" is not well-formed JSON. Perhaps you meant the following:

```
[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"c":3, "d":4}, {"e":5, "f":6}]
```

If it is in a file called `testFile.json`, you can import it as JSON:

```
jsonLst = Import[FileNameJoin[{"path", "to", "testFile.json"}], "JSON"];
```

If the snippet is a string called `str`, you can import it as follows:

```
jsonLst = ImportString[str, "JSON"];
```

In either case, you will have a list of lists of rules:

```
(* jsonLst = {{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2}, {"c" -> 3, "d" -> 4}, {"e" -> 5, "f" -> 6}} *)
```

You can now convert this into the structure you desire. One of the several ways to do it is the following:

```
res = jsonLst // Nest[Map, Apply[List], 2];
(* {{{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}}, {{"c", 3}, {"d", 4}}, {{"e", 5}, {"f", 6}}} *)
```

*EDIT*

Following the suggestion by `Mr. Wizard`, this is indeed more general:

```
res = jsonLst // ReplaceAll[Rule -> List]
```

My intention was to actually give a more restricted solution so as to avoid unintended side-effects.

*EDIT 2*

And following the suggestion by `b3m2a1`, here is his recommended solution:

```
res = jsonLst // Replace[#, Rule -> List, {3}, Heads -> True] &
```

Comment: For the last operation this is more concise and likely more general: `jsonLst /. Rule -> List`

Comment: If you want a more restricted solution that acts like Mr Wizard’s you can use the three argument `Replace`

Comment: Great. Added your solution too.

Answer (score 3):

If you like, you can call the `JSONTools` on the string directly:

```
json = "[{\"a\":1, \"b\":2}, {\"c\":3, \"d\":4}, {\"e\":5, \"f\":6}]";
JSONTools`FromJSON[json]

(* {
   {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2},
   {"c" -> 3, "d" -> 4},
   {"e" -> 5, "f" -> 6}
} *)
```