# how to get association from json?

Tags: associations

How do I convert {{"a" : 13, "z" : 24},{"f" : 17, "h" : 94}} to get

{{"a" -> 13, "z" -> 24},{"f" -> 17, "h" -> 94}}

I am trying to change : to ->

Comment: I thought this question seemed familiar and went looking, and realized you [have asked essentially this before.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178634/convert-json-object-to-list-of-lists)  In what way are the previous answers you received lacking?  I am going to mark this question as "unclear what you are asking" until this is resolved, as there is no point in posting the same answers over and over.

Comment: Same question three times. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/178662/10397

Answer (score 2):

Your input doesn't seem right.  With that corrected you can, in recent versions, use [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) or [`ImportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportString.html):

```
"[{\"a\" : 13, \"z\" : 24},{\"f\" : 17, \"h\" : 94}]";

ImportString[%, "JSON"]

Association /@ %
```

> ```
> {{"z" -> 24, "a" -> 13}, {"f" -> 17, "h" -> 94}}
>
> {<|"z" -> 24, "a" -> 13|>, <|"f" -> 17, "h" -> 94|>}
> ```